# how to simulate a directory browsing url with nginx

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-4

Ususally i maintain  `http://{app-name}.{framework-code}` in my local server running Nginx. For an example a magazine app with Laravel would result in `http://mag.lv4`

But in our client's staging server , the cpanel does not have sub domain support , so directory browising is the only option. There i have to access my app as `http://{client's-domain}.com/applications/magazineapp/index.php`  for Laravel.

i want to simulate this domain url in my localhost. But could not find any convincing guide from Google.

Can somebody help me on this ?

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to handle you website inside a location instead of a separate server, something like this.

```
location /applications/magazineapp {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /applications/magazineapp/index.php;
}
```